# How to remove the specific part of UIScrollview in objective c

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am using UIScrollview for displaying the text using the UILabel.I am using NGVaryingGridView for within the UIScrollview. Now when we add a note to specific label one extra page will be created in the scrollview.

Now i want to delete that space so tell me how to delete that specific width from UIScrollview

Comment: Show your code and what you have tried to 'delete' the content.

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollview` is basically a canvas to add content such that you put it inside and set the scroll area it will show the content and scrolls to the size defined.

Considering that fact itself the delete can be considered as "Removing the contents from the scroll view."

So what you can try out is to look forward and put all the content that must be removed to a single place holder view and remove the view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Collapse the view and correct the content size of your scrollview.  Then remove your collapsed view from the super view.

```
-(void)doStuff {
    //my view is being collapsed and deleted
    [self collapseView:myView complete:^{
        [self.scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width - myView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height))];
        [myView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
-(void)collapseView:(UIView*)view complete:(void(^)(void))complete {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^{
        [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, 0.0, view.frame.size.height)];

        //shift any other views that need to be moved
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(complete) complete();
    }];
}
```